# JavaFX - label size not initialized

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, size, font-size

I am working on an application that enables the user to draw graphs, i.e. edges and nodes. As nodes I am currently using plain JavaFX label elements. When drawing the edges, I need to consider the bounds of the label, however, the width and the height of the labels seem to be initialized only after "drawing" it. E.g., when starting the application the label bounds have a width/height of 0, but if a label is repositioned by the user, the width/height is correct.

Is there a possibility to force JavaFX to draw the current elements? The code is rather complex, but the following gives an idea of what I want to do:

```
stackpane = new StackPane();
text = new Label("Test");
text.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black; -fx-padding:3px;");
stackpane.getChildren().addAll(text);
...
// is it possible to force JavaFX to draw the text here?
...
// some calculations with the bounds of the label
Node node = getLabel();
Bounds bounds = node.getBoundsInParent();
double height = bounds.getHeight();
double width = bounds.getWidth();
```

I also tried to wrap the text in a rectangle and then manually set the width/height of the rectangle. This works, but the nodes have labels of different length and thus manually setting it is not always suitable.

Comment: You may try to bind your logic to node.boundsInParentProperty() changes

Comment: @SergeyGrinev I see how this could work but I do not know how to implement it. I've edited the code a little: How would I achieve a binding of the variable height to the height of the bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to bind your logic to node.boundsInParentProperty() changes

```
public class SmartBorder extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final Label txt = new Label("Example");
        txt.relocate(100, 100);

        Pane root = new Pane();

        final Rectangle border = new Rectangle();
        border.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        border.setStroke(Color.RED);

        // here we autoupdate border 
        txt.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> ov, Bounds old, Bounds b) {
                border.setX(b.getMinX() - 1);
                border.setY(b.getMinY() - 1);
                border.setWidth(b.getWidth()+2);
                border.setHeight(b.getHeight()+2);
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(txt, border);

        // click to see automatic border reaction
        root.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                txt.relocate(Math.random()*200, Math.random()*200);
                txt.setText(Math.random() + "");
            }
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks alot, especially for the detailed example.